# Param get of Laravel

Tags: laravel, get, routes, laravel-5.3

I want to get param of request laravel

In route:  `Route:get(/api/users/{page?}, 'UsersController@listUsers')`
In URL: `localhost/api/users/2?page=7`

How to get page is 2 ?

Comment: Page is 7. User is 2.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Due to Stan's note it's not clear which value do you need

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.4, if you have url with named param you can do this :

> routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/apiUrlCallBack/{id?}{signer?}{status?}', 'ApiController@callbackFunction');
```

And in your ApiController:

> app/Http/Controllers/UniversignController.php

```
public function callbackFunction($id = null,$signer = null,$status = null)
    {
        $signer = Input::get('signer');
        $id = Input::get('id');
        $status = Input::get('status');
        dd($id,$signer,$status);
    }
```

for example my url was :

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/apiUrlCallBack/?signer=65165464&status=455446&id=46464646464`

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get page in controller:

```
public function listUsers($userId = null)
{
    $page = Input::get('page');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you are using.

```
Route:get(/api/users/{page?}, 'UsersController@listUsers') 

In URL: localhost/api/users/2?page=7
```

You want requested page:

Use this :

```
Route::get('/api/user/{page?}, 'UserController@listUsers');
```

In Controller :

```
// $page as you are passing argument in your get request.

function listUsers($page) {

   echo $page;

}
```

on Empty if you are getting error then set default value to null or blank or check if page value is set or not using `is_set`

Laravel 5 Example :

```
Route::get('/api/users/{page?}', function ($page) {
        return $page;
});
```